# angular2 does not load page on server, same thing is working on local machine

Tags: html, .htaccess, angular, iis, angular2-routing

[This is my project structure. I have index.html outside app folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjJzs.png)
When I run my application in local it works proper. Angular2 routing and page rendering is working proper in local machine.

But when I host this application on server. Page routing is not working.

I hav include following code in my web .config to re write URL and then I am able to called index.html page as default page.

`

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Angular2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

`

But yet angular2 page is not rendered.

Also I have released my application in root domain. and included
 `<base href="/">` in index.html page too.

Please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: What's the error ? what do you see when you go there ?

Comment: What are using the transpile it  ? is this typescript ? where is the dist folder ?

Comment: @xe4me I am using typescript to transpile it. On server I am not seeing any error. still my inner page which are routed by angular 2 are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my solution. My internal network(firewall) was blocking my angular 2 app from loading dynamic pages. With the help of network guys I solved that issue.

Apart from it URL rewriting and base path is still needed to load angular app on server.

Thanks.

Comment: What does mean actually "with the help of network guys I solved that issue" ?

Comment: @Jibeee - With help of Network support team, I have request my web site URL from the other server where there was no firewall, and then we came to know that it is firewall in our server which blocks my site to load pages.